# javascript img onload()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `<img>` onload function to trigger the resize action on the image that has been loaded. But I found if in one webpage there is two or more `<img>`s with the same "src", which means the image is the same, the latter `<img>`'s onload() function will not be invoked. How to make sure that all the `<img>`s are properly resized even when there are some `<img>`s with the same src?

Thanks.

Comment: If the `.onload` handler is set before the `.src` property is set on the img tag, the onload handler should fire even if the image comes from the browser cache.  If you set `.src` first (or it's already set in your page's HTML), and then set `.onload`, it may be too late.

Comment: @jfriend00 i use code <img onload="function..." /> to bind, what is the effect corresponding to you description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your browser is actually caching the first image.  So when you attempt to load the same "src" again, it's cached locally and never actually fires an onload.  To get it to load at all times, you could append on a unique value to the query string.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a separate `onload` handler for each `<img/>`, why not just use a single `onload` event for the `window`? This event fires after *everything* (like all the images) have loaded, so you could just process each image in that single handler. Something like:

```
function processAllImages()
{
    var imgElts = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i=0; i<imgElts.length; i++)
    {
        processImage(imgElts[i]); // TODO write this function
    }
}

window.onload = processAllImages;
```

Comment: I can't because my code needs to calculate each image's width&height to do some layout. and some images are load very slowly

Answer (score 1):

I asked similar question before. 
Check this out: [Javascript/jQuery: How to detect img is fully downloaded or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613562/javascript-jquery-how-to-detect-img-is-fully-downloaded-or-not)

In short, you can use 'complete' property of `img` tag. 
check it before you bind load event.